# pmap function in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, pmap

the following code for this sample dataset worked around until October 2020. Please note that this is a sample and I have vast data set. However, when I run it now it does not work.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(readr)
library(tidyr)

"ROW,ISIN,YEAR,DIRECTOR_NAME,DIRECTOR_ID
1,US9898171015,2006,Thomas (Tom) E Davin,2247441792
2,US9898171015,2006,Matthew (Matt) L Hyde,4842568996
3,US9898171015,2007,James (Jim) M Weber,3581636766
4,US9898171015,2007,Matthew (Matt) L Hyde,4842568996
5,US9898171015,2007,David (Dave) M DeMattei,759047198
6,US9898171015,2008,James (Jim) M Weber,3581636766
7,US9898171015,2008,Matthew (Matt) L Hyde,4842568996
8,US9898171015,2008,David (Dave) M DeMattei,759047198
9,US9898171015,2009,William (Bill) Milroy Barnum Jr,20462211719
10,US9898171015,2009,James (Jim) M Weber,3581636766
11,US9898171015,2009,Matthew (Matt) L Hyde,4842568996
12,US9898171015,2009,David (Dave) M DeMattei,759047198
13,US9898171015,2010,William (Bill) Milroy Barnum Jr,20462211719
14,US9898171015,2010,James (Jim) M Weber,3581636766
15,US9898171015,2010,Matthew (Matt) L Hyde,4842568996
16,US9898171015,2011,Sarah (Sally) Gaines McCoy,11434863691
17,US9898171015,2011,William (Bill) Milroy Barnum Jr,20462211719
18,US9898171015,2011,James (Jim) M Weber,3581636766
19,US9898171015,2011,Matthew (Matt) L Hyde,4842568996
20,US9898171015,2012,Sarah (Sally) Gaines McCoy,11434863691
21,US9898171015,2012,Ernest R Johnson,40425210975
22,US9898171015,2013,Sarah (Sally) Gaines McCoy,11434863691
23,US9898171015,2013,Ernest R Johnson,40425210975
24,US9898171015,2013,Travis D Smith,53006212569
25,US9898171015,2014,Sarah (Sally) Gaines McCoy,11434863691
26,US9898171015,2014,Ernest R Johnson,40425210975
27,US9898171015,2014,Travis D Smith,53006212569
28,US9898171015,2015,Kalen F Holmes,11051172801
29,US9898171015,2015,Sarah (Sally) Gaines McCoy,11434863691
30,US9898171015,2015,Ernest R Johnson,40425210975
31,US9898171015,2015,Travis D Smith,53006212569
32,US9898171015,2016,Sarah (Sally) Gaines McCoy,11434863691
33,US9898171015,2016,Ernest R Johnson,40425210975
34,US9898171015,2016,Travis D Smith,53006212569
35,US9898171015,2017,Sarah (Sally) Gaines McCoy,11434863691
36,US9898171015,2017,Scott Andrew Bailey,174000000000
37,US9898171015,2017,Ernest R Johnson,40425210975
38,US9898171015,2017,Travis D Smith,53006212569
" %>% 
  read_csv() %>% 
  group_by(ISIN, YEAR) %>% 
  nest(.key = "OTHER_DATA") %>% 
  group_by(ISIN) %>% 
  mutate(OTHER_DATA_LAG = lag(OTHER_DATA, 1), 
         OTHER_DATA_LEAD = lead(OTHER_DATA, 1), 
         KEEP = pmap(list(OTHER_DATA_LAG, OTHER_DATA, OTHER_DATA_LEAD), function(x, y, z) {
           isTRUE(all_equal(x["DIRECTOR_ID"], y["DIRECTOR_ID"])) || 
           isTRUE(all_equal(y["DIRECTOR_ID"], z["DIRECTOR_ID"]))
         })) %>% 
  filter(unlist(KEEP)) %>% 
  select(-OTHER_DATA_LAG, -OTHER_DATA_LEAD, -KEEP) %>% 
  unnest() %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Then I put a post here and someone helped me with the following code -

```
library(tidyverse)

ceo1 %>% 
  group_by(ISIN, YEAR) %>% 
  nest(OTHER_DATA = c(ROW, DIRECTOR_NAME, DIRECTOR_ID)) %>% 
  group_by(ISIN) %>% 
  mutate(OTHER_DATA_LAG = lag(OTHER_DATA, 1), 
         OTHER_DATA_LEAD = lead(OTHER_DATA, 1),
         KEEP = pmap_lgl(list(OTHER_DATA_LAG, OTHER_DATA, OTHER_DATA_LEAD), function(x, y, z) {
           if(length(x) > 0 && length(y) > 0 && length(z) > 0)
                isTRUE(all_equal(x["DIRECTOR_ID"], y["DIRECTOR_ID"])) ||
                isTRUE(all_equal(y["DIRECTOR_ID"], z["DIRECTOR_ID"]))
           else FALSE
         })) %>% 
  filter(KEEP) %>% 
  select(-OTHER_DATA_LAG, -OTHER_DATA_LEAD, -KEEP) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(OTHER_DATA)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

This worked perfect for this **SAMPLE** dataset, but when I apply it in my **LARGE DATASET**, it worked but the problem is - I do not get the same observations of what I get when I ran the old code (this first code here). It seems the problem is with `pmap` function because it generates `NULL` and which has issues.
Here are links of my two previous codes -

First one - [Filtering data using dplyr function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56530713/filtering-data-using-dplyr-function-in-r)
Second one - [Issues with tidyverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66434816/issues-with-tidyverse)

Anybody can shed some light so that I can run my old code (First one)?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a dataset which behaves differently using two different codes that you have so that it is easier to compare why you are getting different outputs using the codes.

Meanwhile, you can try this code :

```
df %>%
  group_by(YEAR) %>%
  summarise(DIRECTOR_ID = list(DIRECTOR_ID)) %>%
  mutate(flag = map2_lgl(DIRECTOR_ID, lag(DIRECTOR_ID),
                     ~length(.x) == length(.y) && all(sort(.x) == sort(.y)))) %>%
  filter(flag | lead(flag)) %>%
  select(YEAR) %>%
  left_join(df, by = 'YEAR')

#   YEAR   ROW ISIN         DIRECTOR_NAME              DIRECTOR_ID
#   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>        <chr>                            <dbl>
# 1  2007     3 US9898171015 James (Jim) M Weber         3581636766
# 2  2007     4 US9898171015 Matthew (Matt) L Hyde       4842568996
# 3  2007     5 US9898171015 David (Dave) M DeMattei      759047198
# 4  2008     6 US9898171015 James (Jim) M Weber         3581636766
# 5  2008     7 US9898171015 Matthew (Matt) L Hyde       4842568996
# 6  2008     8 US9898171015 David (Dave) M DeMattei      759047198
# 7  2013    22 US9898171015 Sarah (Sally) Gaines McCoy 11434863691
# 8  2013    23 US9898171015 Ernest R Johnson           40425210975
# 9  2013    24 US9898171015 Travis D Smith             53006212569
#10  2014    25 US9898171015 Sarah (Sally) Gaines McCoy 11434863691
#11  2014    26 US9898171015 Ernest R Johnson           40425210975
#12  2014    27 US9898171015 Travis D Smith             53006212569
```

Comment: Thanks for your code, but my old code do not run now so I cannot create a new dataset. Basically, I did not save the output from my code. I just ran them and saved the results for my research. Now when I try to run the code and it does not produce the old result and I find that the number of observations from new code is different from the number of observation in old code. I am getting worried as I did not find any ways to run my old code to get my previous results.

Comment: Instead of focussing on the code I think we should focus on the problem that you are trying to solve. I read your original post and have updated my answer to get you the expected output based on that. Can you try that @Sharif